# Calculate a column of times to find the difference against a static time

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula

In Excel, how can I calculate a column time differences from a static time?

Example shown below. I want to know how many minutes past `08:00 AM` the value in each row is.

Desired result:

```
Column A, input      | Col B, Difference in minutes compared to 08:00 AM
                     |
1/11/2016 7:55:00 AM | -5
1/11/2016 7:57:00 AM | -3
1/11/2016 7:57:00 AM | -3
1/11/2016 7:58:00 AM | -2
1/11/2016 7:59:00 AM | -1
1/11/2016 7:59:00 AM | -1
1/11/2016 8:03:00 AM | 3
1/11/2016 8:06:00 AM | 6
1/11/2016 8:15:00 AM | 15
1/11/2016 8:25:00 AM | 25
```

What is the formula for this?

Comment: `=MOD(A1,1)-TIME(8,0,0)` and be sure to format the cells as Custom Format `[m]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=((HOUR(A1)-HOUR(TIME(8,0,0)))*60)+(MINUTE(A1)-MINUTE(TIME(8,0,0)))
```